# How do I get my React Native Flatlist to reload on realm data updates?

Tags: react-native, realm, react-native-flatlist

I'm using an array I get from my realm database to render a flatlist of tasks, however when I change stuff on the database the list won't rerender unless I leave the page. And I'm not sure how to instruct it to, had I been using redux I would give it state as extradata, but here I'm not sure what to do.

Some code snippets:

```
  async componentWillMount() {
try {
  let realm = await Realm.open({
    schema: [TaskSchema]
  });
  this.setState({ realm });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log('we screwed boys');
}
```

How I update database without leaving the page:

```
onDeleteClick = () => {
const realm = this.state.realm;
realm.write(() => {
  let completedTasks = this.state.realm.objects('Task').filtered('isComplete = true');
  realm.delete(completedTasks);
});
```

flat list declaration in render() :

```
let tasks = null;
if (this.state.realm) {
  tasks = this.state.realm.objects('Task');
}
return (
  <View style={styles.backgroundStyle}>
    <FlatList
      data={tasks}
      renderItem={this.renderTasks}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.title}
    />
```

edit: note - it does delete items from the database correctly, the list just doesn't know to rerender appearantly and I don't know how to instruct it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try setting the realm object again after deleting the tasks then it should re-render the list

```
 onDeleteClick = () => {
      const realm = this.state.realm;
      realm.write(() => {
        let completedTasks = this.state.realm
          .objects("Task")
          .filtered("isComplete = true");
        realm.delete(completedTasks);

        this.setState({
          realm, // set realm object using setState to re render the list.
        });
      });
    };
```